# Cron job terminates early

Tags: bash, cron

In my crontab file I execute a script like so (I edit the crontab using `sudo crontab -e`):

```
01 * * * * bash /etc/m/start.sh
```

The script runs some other scripts like so:

```
sudo bash -c "/etc/m/abc.sh --option=1" &
sleep 2
sudo bash -c "/etc/m/abc.sh --option=2" &
```

When cron runs the script `start.sh`, I do `ps aux | grep abc.sh` and I see the `abc.sh` script running.

After a couple of seconds, the script is no longer running, even though `abc.sh` should take hours to finish.

If I do `sudo bash /etc/m/start.sh &` from the command line, everything works fine (the `abc.sh` scripts run for hours in the background until they complete).

How do I debug this?

Is there something I'm doing that is preventing these scripts from running in the background until they are done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program(s) you're starting might be expecting a terminal to send their output to, or receive input from.

If you set the `MAILTO=` variable, and you have a sendmail(-like) daemon installed, you will get an email with the error message(s) it prints, if there are any:

```
MAILTO=your@email.address.here.com
01 * * * * bash /path/to/something.sh
```

Another way to debug would be to run the script from the command line, while redirecting all inputs and outputs:

```
$ sudo bash -c "foo.sh" > output_file 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

Also, the system log files (usually found in `/var/log`) might contain useful hints.